Is anyone not an utilitarian?
Even for those schools of thought with certain required or forbidden actions that don’t seem to align with the goal of “optimization of happiness,” can’t these obligations also be viewed as “fulfilling one’s inner needs” and thus incorporated into happiness? With this argument, is it possible to truly not be a utilitarian at all?

Yes. That something "also can be viewed" differently does not mean much, anything can be viewed in all sorts of ways. Deontologists and virtue ethicists "can also view" utilitarianism as a distorted version of their own ethics. But approaches to ethical issues are very different in those three frameworks. Discharging duties or pursuing virtues works very differently from optimizing a utility (not necessarily "happiness", by the way), and even prescriptions in concrete cases often clash.

How would you explain the various schools of asceticism?  Do you mean to say that even those who actively flee happiness seek happiness?  Beware the temptation to broaden the definition of terms ad infinitum: words that mean anything mean nothing.  If all feeling is "happiness", then it's not "happiness" anymore, it's just "feeling".

You posit someone who takes actions based on whether the acts "[fulfil] one’s inner needs” and that this concept is "thus incorporated into happiness."
That is not a match with traditional conceptions of utilitarianism. Utilitarianism is not about maximizing one's own happiness.

What distinguishes utilitarianism from egoism has to do with the scope of the relevant consequences. On the utilitarian view one ought to maximize the overall good — that is, consider the good of others as well as one's own good.


What if the question is "does everyone take actions to fulfill one's inner needs?" The question might be vague though.
